# How is it possible to publish data with ArcGIS Server without creating ArcSDE service or using ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase

I am still relatively new to the ESRI server techologies. I have server1 which runs ArcGIS server 10.0 and when I look at which processes running on this server I see ArcSOM.exe, ArcSOCMON.exe and many ArcSOC.exe (probably around 50 instances)

I have another server (server2) which runs 6 instances of giomgr.exe 11 instances of gsrvr.exe and 2 Imgrd.exe instances.

There are also 2 DBMS Servers which hold sde-geodatabase data.

My question is how have I been able to publish data from a file geodatabase stored on a partition on server2 although there is no SOC, SOM, DBMS or AGS running from it?

Comment: Do you want to publish a map service on server1 containing data from a file geodatabase locally on another machine (server2)?

Comment: My end-question (just re-edited) is based on trying to understand how existing data is served through AGS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to publish an ArcGIS Server service, you need to author a resource (a map document, for example) that would contain some data which can be local (that is, stored on the same machine where you have your ArcGIS Server installed) or stored at a shared location (such a shared folder). What you need to do then is to make sure ArcGIS Server ArcGIS Server specifically ArcGISSOC account has access to the resources you are trying to publish.

Here is the [Tutorial: Publishing a map service](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//00930000000p000000)

When the service will be published, the client sends request to the ArcGIS Server (server1). The SOM (think manager) component asks SOC (think workhorse) to get the data needed. The SOC process (run by ArcGISSOC OS account will go to the server2 and get the file geodatabase data provided that it has file and share permissions applied). The composed data will be compiled as a raster image (in case of map service) or as a raw data (geodata service) and sent to the client side.

Read more about [Preparing resources for publishing as services](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Preparing_resources_for_publishing_as_services/00930000005v000000/)

PS. In case you will get a chance to upgrade, switch to 10.1/10.2 which have a more robust architecture and provides a better server platform comparing to 10.0. Esri will retire 10.0 in the upcoming years, too, so don't spend too much time learning outdated technology (unless really needed).

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately my problem is that I have to solve some problems on the old architecture before we can upgrade. When we get 10.2 in about 6 months, ill have to learn everything again.

Comment: Can you tell me anything about performance when using the connection described about as compared to using and sde service to publish the same data?

Comment: From fastest to slowest: local file geodatabase > remote file geodatabase / local SDE geodatabase > remote file geodatabase > remote SDE geodatabase. Choose to use direct connect for SDE instead of app server (SDE service), it is as a rule faster. Cache your data whenever you can too. Pre-cook your datasets and avoid any unneccessary processing on-demand.

Answer (score 0):

It is even much easier in 10.1 and 10.2. You add your data to ArcMap which is the authoring tool, share as service. Select the service site and publish.

If you would like to edit your data through the service,you should use an enterprise geodatabase.